# Httpheaders and what to do?

Tags: angular, http, post, http-headers

Sorry for my english.

addUser(newUser): Observable{
let json = JSON.stringify(newUser);

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

return this._peticiones.post(this.url+'api/users',json,{headers:headers})
```

}

i need what to do that {headers:headers}? why i need it?
I am learning to programming.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP headers are used to pass additional information to your backend. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers/#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20headers%20are%20used,in%20clear-text%20string%20format.) you can find more information.

You can declare the HTTP header like this:

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
```

And can call:

```
return this._peticiones.post(this.url + 'api/users', json, this.httpOptions)
```